# Unable to create table with column name "schemas"

Tags: mysql

When I tried to execute following statement.

```
create table user_schemas (user_id varchar(255) not null, schemas varchar(255));
```

I am getting following error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'schemas varchar(255))' at line 1
```

When I change the column name "schemas" to something else, it is working fine.

```
mysql> create table user_schemas (user_id varchar(255) not null, schemas varchar(255));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'schemas varchar(255))' at line 1
mysql> 
mysql> create table user_schemas (user_id varchar(255) not null, rules varchar(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use reserved words in the SQL syntax you must use Backticks **(`)** like:

```
create table user_schemas (
    user_id varchar(255) not null, 
    `schemas` varchar(255)
);
```